# work versus works

Tags: grammatical-number

which of the sample sentences below sounds better, or are they both OK?

1) We can conduct electric equipment works and mechanical equipment works in your factories.

2) We can conduct electric equipment work and mechanical equipment work in your factories.

Thank you.

Comment: "works" are things you have made, and is mostly archaic: "Look on my Works, ye Mighty, and despair!"

Comment: @nohat I think there are at least two usages of *works* that aren't archaic -- works of art as in the complete *works of Mozart* and industrial plants as in *steel works*.

Comment: I totally expected such a lowly upvoted yet popular question to receive a possible duplicate complaint!

Answer (score 1):

"*We can conduct electric equipment **work** and mechanical equipment **work** in your factories*" is grammatically the correct sentence.

> **1-Work (activity) uncountable noun.**  ( [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-nouns/work-noun))
>
> an activity, such as a job, that a person uses physical or mental
>   effort to do, usually for money:
>
> *I've got so much work to do.*
>
> *What sort of work are you experienced in?*
>
> **2-work (CREATION) countable no**un ​  something created as a result of effort, especially a painting, book, or piece of music:
>
> *The museum has many works by Picasso as well as other modern painters.*
>
> *The poetic works of Tagore.*
>
> **3- works (FACTORY) (countable plural)** ​
>
> *An industrial building, especially one where a lot of people are employed:*
>
> *A steel/iron works.*
>
> **4- works [ plural ]​ (machine)**
>
> the parts of a machine, especially those that move:
>
> *If you take the back off this clock, you can see its/the works.*

from **[English Grammar Today](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-nouns/work-noun)**

> ***Work as an uncountable noun***
>
> Work is an uncountable noun when it means something we do that takes
>   an effort, often as part of a job or for study:
>
> *Hard work is good for you. It keeps you fit. (work as a physical activity)*
>
> *I’m not going out tonight. I’ve got a lot of work to do. We’ve got
>   exams next week. (work as study)*

**Warning:**

> We don’t use work with the indefinite article (a) or in the plural.
>   The word for a specific occupation or task is job, which is a
>   countable noun:
>
> They offered me a job.
>
> **Not**: They offered me a work …

**At work**

We can say that someone is at work when they are at the place where they work and are doing their job:

Can I ring you back later? I’m at work at the moment and I can’t
 really talk privately.

> > **Work as a countable noun**
> >
> > Work as a countable noun means something created, especially a book or
> >     painting or piece of music or sculpture:
>
> *She bought me the complete works of Shakespeare for my birthday.*
>
> *Several works of art were stolen from the town museum yesterday.*